# How are variables like GTEST_FOUND set?

Tags: cmake

I'm trying to see how `GTEST_FOUND` is set when `find_package(GTest REQUIRED)` is called, but there's no sign of the variable `GTEST_FOUND` being set in this file:

https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/FindGTest.cmake

Does anyone know how the variable is set if it's not done in `FindGTest.cmake`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `GTEST_FOUND` variable is actually set in the [`FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake`](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake) file. You can see in `FindGTest.cmake`, a call to this function is made here:

```
include(${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake)
FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS(GTest DEFAULT_MSG GTEST_LIBRARY GTEST_INCLUDE_DIR GTEST_MAIN_LIBRARY)
```

The `FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS` function uses the first argument for the package name (`GTest` in this case) to set the `<PackageName>_FOUND` variable.

Here is a quote from the header information for the `FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS` function:

> The `<PackageName>_FOUND` variable will be set to `TRUE` if all
>     the variables `<required-var>...` are valid and any optional
>     constraints are satisfied, and `FALSE` otherwise.  A success or
>     failure message may be displayed based on the results and on
>     whether the `REQUIRED` and/or `QUIET` option was given to
>     the :command:`find_package` call.